# Reload forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django

Имею форму для админки:

```
class PermissionModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  queryset = MyGroup.objects.all()
  for group_object in queryset:
    exec('group_{0} = forms.BooleanField()'.format(group_object.group_name))

  class Meta:
    model = MyPermission
    fields = ('permission_name', 'permission_description')
```

В ней задаются поля согласно имеющимся группам. Проблема в том, что они создаются во время запуска сервера. Как перезагрузить форму, скажем, после добавления/удаления/редактирования группы? Форма группы:

```
class GroupModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyGroup
    fields = ('group_name', 'group_tag')

  def save(self, commit=True):
    group = super(GroupnModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if commit:
      group.save()
    return group
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее в данном случае создавать поля динамически в методе `__init__`:

```
class PermissionModelForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for group_object in MyGroup.objects.all():
            self.fields['group_{}'.format(group_object.group_name))] = forms.BooleanField()
```